# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in HTML - can't solve

Tags: html, console, syntax-error, token

Can anyone help me find this unexpected token? I've been looking at this code for a while so maybe i need a fresh pair of eyes to solve this. 
see HTML code below:

```
<div class="list-view hide">
                    <table class="custom-reports-table">
                        <script id="custom-reports-table" type="text/javascript">
                        <tbody>
                             {{#each listItem}}
                                <tr class="row" id="{{itemId}}">
                                    <td class="select-container">
                                        <div class="select-container">
                                            <input id="{{itemId}}"type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="preview-container"> 
                                        <i class="icon icon-pictos-115"></i>
                                        <i class="icon icon-pictos-172"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-asterisk report-type-icon"></i>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="report-info">
                                        <h3 class="report-name">{{itemName}}</h3>
                                        <p class="summary">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                            tempor incididunt.
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row-actions">
                                        <a class="tooltip tip-btn-duplicate" href="#">
                                            <span class="duplicate">Duplicate</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-copy btn-duplicate-item"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="tooltip tip-btn-generate" href="#">
                                            <span class="generate">Generate</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o btn-generate-item"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="tooltip tip-btn-schedule" href="#">
                                            <span class="schedule">Schedule</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o btn-schedule-item"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="tooltip tip-btn-remove btn-remove-item" href="#">
                                            <span class="remove-report">Remove</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o btn-remove-item"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                             {{/each}}
                        </tbody>
                        </script>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- end of: .list-view-->
```

According to the console It looks like the error is somewhere related to the tbody but i can't find anything wrong. Anyone know what it might be? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML? I assume you're using a templating engine (ie: `{{itemId}}`).

Comment: Sure, i included it in a js fiddle since its long, it includes both rendered and handlebar template http://jsfiddle.net/bx0vm162/

Comment: Is that the actual HTML the server receives and this is a client-side templating language?

Comment: Also the full error message with pointers to the right line would help.

Comment: Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
Line : <div class="list-view hide">
                        <table class="custom-reports-table">
                            <script id="custom-reports-table" type="text/javascript">
                            <tbody> //here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `type` of `<script>` correctly:

```
<script id="custom-reports-table" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

If you're telling the browser to evaluate HTML as Javascript, of course you'll get syntax errors from the Javascript interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is a JavaScript error:

```
<script id="custom-reports-table" type="text/javascript">
    <tbody>
    // Much HTML...
    </tbody>
</script>
```

You try to run some HTML markup as JavaScript.
Either you missed the `<script>` tag there, or you don't know how JavaScript works.
In that case I'm unable to tell what your intention is with that, but that's most likely the source of your error.

Comment: I am using handlebars. it works in other pages just an unexpected token error in this one

Comment: Do your research ;) it does

Comment: @user22 I'm sorry, but you're wrong. A handlebars template and actual JavaScript code are two **very** different things. The information that you use handlebars was vital in this situation and should have been included in the question. Without it, your code is just plain invalid. *Details matter.*